# Why is VS Code not colouring paired brackets after update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After the **VS Code** update, the **Bracket Pair Colorizer** extension became unnecessary, because in VS Code this extension by default colours the paired brackets itself. But it is not working for me. I've tried different ways, reinstalling **Bracket Pair Colorizer**, manually adjusting in `setting.json`, but nothing helps.

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
```

VS Code Help: Info output:

```
Version: 1.81.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

When disabling all extensions with the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command, paired brackets are still not coloured:

[image: Brackets not colorized example]

If anyone has also faced this problem, please share how did you solve this problem.

Comment: not working for you in what language modes? All language modes? Show a [mre].

Comment: @starball colour theme  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro Flat".
I tried removing all parameters from the setting.json file, but that didn't help.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: I suggest that you raise an issue ticket. Use the `Help > Report Issue` feature of VS Code. Provide as much detail as possible about how to reproduce the problem. Ping me with a link to your issue ticket once you raise it.

Comment: @starball, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191302